# VBA How to trigger Macro when columns are updated by the user and not VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, infinite-loop

I am having a problem of an infinite loop which is caused by the code below.

It is caused by changes in column E affecting changes in G and vice-versa constantly triggering `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

In the below code I could stop this with a line that tests if the last change was made by the user or by VBA. Is there a way to test this condition?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:E")) Is Nothing Then Macro
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then Macro2
End Sub

Private Sub Macro()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Range("E1:E10")
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
                cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = cell.Value + cell.Offset(0, 1)
            End If
        Else
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Macro2()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Range("G1:G10")
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = cell.Value - cell.Offset(0, -1)
            End If
        Else
            cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Application.Enable events?

Comment: Yes, I figured out Application.EnableEvents = False before the changes and Application.EnableEvents = true after solved this problem.

Comment: @user1088793 ...so you've resolved this issue?

Answer (score 2):

temporarily disable events triggering:

```
Private Sub Macro()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Range("E1:E10")

    On Error GoTo HandleExit ' assure proper handling of any error
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'disable events triggering

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
              cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = cell.Value + cell.Offset(0, 1)
            End If
        Else
              cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = 1
        End If
    Next

HandleExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'enable back events triggering

End Sub
```

the same with Macro2

---

**EDIT** to add a possible refactoring of the code

BTW, your `Sub Macro()` could be rewritten with no loops and without relying on `IsNumeric()` function (which is not 100% reliable (e.g. `IsNumeric("12.5.3"`) would return `True`)

```
Private Sub Macro()
    On Error GoTo HandleExit ' assure proper handling of any error
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'disable events triggering

    With Range("E1:E10") 'reference your range
        If WorksheetFunction.Count(.Cells) > 0 Then ' if any "truly" numeric values in referenced range
            With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Offset(, 2) ' reference referenced range cells with constant numeric content only
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(RC[-1]:RC[-2])" ' write needed formula
                .Value = .Value ' get rid of the formula
            End With
        End If

        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(, 2).Value = 1 ' if any blank cell in referenced range then fill it with 1"
    End With

HandleExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'enable back events triggering

End Sub
```